# Bash variable expension

Tags: bash

I would like to do this kind of thing in bash:

```
OPT="val1 val2=\"info\""
CMD="mycommand -a $OPT file.cfg"
```

and I get:

```
mycommand -a 'val1' 'val2="info" ' file.cfg
```

instead I would like to have:

```
mycommand -a 'val1 val2="info" ' file.cfg
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just single quote $OPT as such:

```
CMD="mycommand -a '$OPT' file.cfg"
```

Result:

```
$ echo $CMD
mycommand -a 'val1 val2="info"' file.cfg
```

Comment: NP, don't forget to accept the answer and save time to other users looking for  a question to answer ;)